# how find an object in std::vector

Tags: c++, vector, std

I have an object like below

```
 class MyClass{
   int a;
   double b;
 };
```

and

```
 vector<MyClass> vMyClass;
```

then I want search in vMyClass try to use algorithm function:

```
 if( std::find(vMyClass.begin(), vMyClass.end(), aiField) == vMyClass.end())
```

I also defined `operator==`

```
 int operator ==(Field &Left,Field &Right)
 {
    return memcmp(&Left,&Right,sizeof(Field));
 }
```

or

```
int operator ==(Field &Right)
{
    return memcmp(this,&Right,sizeof(Field));
}
```

but I get an error message.

```
1>c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include\algorithm(40) : error C2678: binary '==' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'MyClass' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
1>        C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\include\guiddef.h(192): could be 'int operator ==(const GUID &,const GUID &)' [found using argument-dependent lookup]
1>        c:\users\shmuelian\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\src\examples\DLgenerator\DLParser.h(85): or       'int operator ==(MyClass &,MyClass &)' [found using argument-dependent lookup]
1>        c:\users\shmuelian\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\src\examples\DLgenerator\DLParser.h(70): or       'int MyClass::operator ==(MyClass &)'
1>        while trying to match the argument list '(MyClass, const MyClass)'
1>        c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include\algorithm(74) : see reference to function template instantiation '_InIt std::_Find<std::_Vector_iterator<_Ty,_Alloc>,_Ty>(_InIt,_InIt,const _Ty &)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _InIt=std::_Vector_iterator<MyClass,std::allocator<MyClass>>,
1>            _Ty=MyClass,
1>            _Alloc=std::allocator<MyClass>
1>        ]
1>        c:\users\shmuelian\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\src\examples\DLgenerator\DLParser.h(108) : see reference to function template instantiation '_InIt std::find<std::_Vector_iterator<_Ty,_Alloc>,MyClass>(_InIt,_InIt,const _Ty &)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _InIt=std::_Vector_iterator<MyClass,std::allocator<MyClass>>,
1>            _Ty=MyClass,
1>            _Alloc=std::allocator<MyClass>
1>        ]
1>CommandArgParser.cpp
1>Generating Code...
```

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: To save yourself never try to mix C functions with C++. memcmp doesn't know about classes and objects

Comment: Even in C, `memcmp` is not generally useful for comparing structures, which may have arbitrary padding between fields. You'd have to be sure that the padding was zero-initialised.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

They need to be const references. And `memcmp` is really, really bad- just perform a member-wise comparison.

Comment: And `operator==` should return a `bool` (which has the exact opposite logic than `std::memcmp`).

Comment: +1 - memcmp() will compare padding which can be whatever values.

Answer (score 7):

You forgot the `const` qualifier in your `==` operator, plus it should return `bool`, not `int`.  Just use this instead:

```
bool operator ==(const Field &Left, const Field &Right)
{
    return (Left.a == Right.a) && (Left.b == Right.b);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a vector of `MyClass`, but an comparision operator for `Field`. You have to write an
`bool operator == (const MyClass &, const MyClass &)`.

This operator should (as others indicated), not use `memcmp`, but rather perform a member-wise comparison.

Comment: Actually, that trailing `const` is only necessary when you make that a member function, something [which I would advice against](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading/4421729#4421729).

Comment: @Tomalak: Hey, I'm a bloody furriner!

Answer (score 1):

Implement the operator within the class itself:

```
class MyClass
{    
public:
    int a;    
    double b;  

    bool operator ==(const MyClass &Right) const
    {      
        return (a == Right.a) && (b == Right.b);  // 'this' is left
    } 
};
```